# Дисциплинирована или дисциплинированна?

Tags: орфография

Встречаются обе формы, значение прямое (непереносное), однородные отношения с другими прилагательными. И как тогда **отличить причастие от прилагательного** или можно не отличать (авторский выбор)?

**1) Дисциплинирована**

В течение всех лет обучения имела высокий учебный рейтинг по всем дисциплинам. Коммуникабельна, **дисциплинирована**, пунктуальна, инициативна, целеустремленна [Резюме выпускника МНЭПУ (2004)]

― Девочка им мешает? ― Всякая девочка, если она недостаточно **дисциплинирована**… ― Я вас спрашиваю ― сестры жалуются или нет? [Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек (1961)]

**2) Дисциплинированна**

Теперешняя наша горничная, правда, толста и, быть может, имеет слабость к перчаткам и платкам, но зато она вполне прилична, **дисциплинированна** и не визжит, когда ее щиплет Кукушкин. [А. П. Чехов. Рассказ неизвестного человека (1893)]

Она и в самом деле была **дисциплинированна**, аккуратна, точна, и все это из-за преданной, поистине бескорыстной любви к кино, бескорыстной, потому что статисты, в сущности, получали до обидного мало. [Людмила Уварова. Артистка // Библиотека «Огонек», 1990]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дисциплинировать кого? что? –  приучать к дисциплине.
Поэтому дисциплинирована что сделана?  -  краткое причастие, (та, которую приучили к дисциплине ).
Дисциплинированна какова? – краткое прилагательное, ( подчиняющаяся дисциплине, соблюдающая строгий порядок).
(С.И.Ожегов, Н.Ю.Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка.)

Я согласна с Вами, Сибилла, разница в лексическом значении  небольшая, в основном в грамматических признаках.

Comment: А писать-то как?  Мне кажется, если есть однородный ряд прилагательных, то пишем две  НН в прилагательном. Тогда в резюме надо писать "дисциплинированна". А причастие реже встречается, например: она недостаточно дисциплинирована.

Comment: В резюме, конечно, дисциплинированна (она подчиняется дисциплине).Вы сами себе и ответили.